# A hook for end each ajax request in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, caching

I'd like to create a custom ajax cache for each request and that's why I need a hook to be executed after each ajax action.

I created my custom 'ajax.php' file, placed it to the website root directory. And there are silly code lines like that:

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'] ?? null;
...
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $action );
else do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $action );
die('TheEnd');
```

But i cannot see 'TheEnd' after each ajax output. I tried to debug the `function do_action( $tag, ...$arg )` from `wp-includes/plugin.php` and for now i have no idea how to handle it in the correct way. I tried to create my custom 'do_action' function, but in that case I have to overwrite the `WP_Hook` object and it's been marked as `final`.

Any help/thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone faces with similar issue, see the code of Heartbeat Control plugin below. (I am sure, there are similar plugins, that's was the first in google for me.)

I tried to prepare my custom solution, that's why I asked the question.But there are ready examples for ajax cache, here is one:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/reduce-admin-ajax-php-related-server-load-wordpress/

So it helped for me to get quick solution, and there in the source code are few helpful WP hooks to sort out the issue.